# Dynamic Survey DB Model - Display Questions based on Logic

Tags: database, design-patterns, database-design

I am building a survey application that allows users to create and distribute surveys.

I have the survey DB model almost complete, with the exception of handling 1 part.

I want users to be able to add logic to the survey.

Below is my current DB model, how can I modify this to handle custom logic. Is this even possible?

By logic I mean to show/hide question based on the answer to other questions.

I.e. **If** (Question 1 == true), **then** (show Question) 2 **else** (show Question 3).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can extrapolate you survey logic as directed graph. So each state will be represent the replay stage and transition will be represent logic of survey based on previous  replies.

Comment: I'll be honest, your answer is a little over my head.I'm just going to assume you are on to something. I'm a designer turner programmer, not a mathematician/comp sci major. That being said, I will definitely read up on directed graphs and how I can  "extrapolate" my survey logic with this. Thanks for your input. If you have any good resources on this type of algorithm/logic, it would be great if you could share.

Comment: Thx. I think wiki will be enough  to catch the basic idea of graph. Not sure "extrapolate" right term. May be "model" more suitable. I describe wide model, but you can use more narrow.  Each state(vertix) is answer, and selected replay is transition(edge) to next state. And if this model suitable - model it's in database.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <style>
    /* Center the content of the page */
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  
  /* Style the title */
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 1em 0;
  }
  
  /* Style the questions */
  .question {
    margin: 1em 0;
    width: 50%;
  }
  
  /* Style the labels */
  label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  /* Style the select elements */
  select {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    font-size: 1em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  
  /* Style the text input elements */
  input[type="text"] {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    font-size: 1em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  
  /* Style the submit button */
  button[type="submit"] {
    display: block;
    margin: 2em auto;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    background-color: #0066cc;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
  }
  
  /* Style the option elements within the select element */
  select option {
    font-size: 1em;
  }

  .question.dependent {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .question.dependent.hidden {
    display: none !important;
  }
  
  
   </style>
    <title>Questionnaire</title>
</head>

<body class="background">
    <h1>Questionnaire</h1>

    <div class="question" id="q1">
        <label>Are you a student?</label>
        <select>
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="no">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="question" id="q2">
        <label>What is your Qualification?</label>
        <select>
            <option value="10">Matriculation</option>
            <option value="12">Intermediate</option>
            <option value="Grad">Graduation</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="question" id="q3">
        <label>What is your major?</label>
        <select>
            <option value="cs">Computer Science</option>
            <option value="eng">Engineering</option>
            <option value="art">Art</option>
        </select>
    </div>


    <div class="question" id="q4">
        <label>Do you have a job?</label>
        <select>
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="no">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="question" id="q5">
        <label>What is your job title?</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>

    <div class="question" id="q6">
        <label>Are you searching for job</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    
let questionnaire = {
  "questions": [
    {
      "id": "q1",
      "showQuestion": [
        {
          "response": "Yes",
          "dependentQuestions": ["q2", "q3"]
        },
        {
          "response": "No",
          "dependentQuestions": ["q4"]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "q4",
      "showQuestion": [
        {
          "response": "Yes",
          "dependentQuestions": ["q5"]
        },
        {
          "response": "No",
          "dependentQuestions": ["q6"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};


// Wait for the DOM to load
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  // Get all the questions
  const questions = document.querySelectorAll('.question');

  // Loop through all the questions
  questions.forEach(function(question) {

    // Get the select/input element and the ID of the question
    const selectInput = question.querySelector('select, input');
    const questionId = question.id;

    // Check if the question has a dependent question
    const dependentQuestion = questionnaire.questions.find(q => q.id === questionId);

    // If the question has a dependent question
    if (dependentQuestion) {

      // Listen for changes to the select/input element
      selectInput.addEventListener('change', function() {

        // Get the selected value
        const selectedValue = selectInput.value;

        // Loop through all the dependent questions
        dependentQuestion.showQuestion.forEach(function(showQuestion) {

          // If the selected value matches the response
          if (selectedValue === showQuestion.response) {

            // Show the dependent questions
            showQuestion.dependentQuestions.forEach(function(dependentQuestionId) {
              const dependentQuestion = document.getElementById(dependentQuestionId);
              dependentQuestion.style.display = 'block';
            });

          } else {

            // Hide the dependent questions
            showQuestion.dependentQuestions.forEach(function(dependentQuestionId) {
              const dependentQuestion = document.getElementById(dependentQuestionId);
              dependentQuestion.style.display = 'none';
            });

          }

        });

      });

    }

  });

});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).